# Why is my serial monitor showing the binary value updating every other cycle where as the decimal is every cycle? - Arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

**Project Context:**
This is code I wrote for my arduino to try and create a binary clock, where I create a 24 length array of boleans to define a binary clock.
the array is broken down like this:
00|0000|000|0000|000|0000
H1| H2 | M1| M2 | S1| S2

I intent to use 3 8 Bit shift registers to control the output LEDs, so this could be broken up 1 nibble per digit however I did not do that......not sure why.

**TLDR:**
I made this shit code, it is currently only incrememnting the binary value that's printed every other cycle and the decimal every cycle, would anyone be able to help me figure out why?

`

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  int h1 = 0;
  int h2 = 0;
  int m1 = 0;
  int m2 = 0;
  int s1 = 0;
  int s2 = -1;



  while(0 == 0)
  {
     // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  s2 = s2 + 1;
  if (s2 == 10)
  {
    s2 = 0;
    s1 = s1 + 1;
    if ( s1 == 6)
    {
      s1 = 0;
      m2 = m2 + 1;
      if ( m2 == 10)
      {
        m2 = 0;
        m1 = m1 + 1;
        if (m1 == 6)
        {
          m1 = 0;
          h2 = h2 + 1;
          if ( h2 == 10 ) 
          {
            h2 = 0;
            h1 = h1 + 1;
          }
          else if ((h2 == 5) && (h1 == 2))
          {
            h1 = 0;
            h2 = 0;

          }

        }
      }
    }
  }

  stringSetter(h1,h2,m1,m2,s1,s2);

  delay(1000);
  }
 
}

void stringSetter(int h1, int h2, int m1, int m2, int s1, int s2) 
{



  //h1 - converting to boolean array
  boolean h1b[2];
  if ( h1 == 0 ) 
  {
    h1b[0] = 0;
    h1b[1] = 0;
  }
  else  if ( h1 == 1 ) 
  {
    h1b[0] = 1;
    h1b[1] = 0;
  }
  else  if ( h1 == 2 ) 
  {
    h1b[0] = 0;
    h1b[1] = 1;
  }

  //h2 - converting to boolean array
  boolean h2b[4];
  if ( h2 == 0 ) 
  {
    h2b[0] = 0;
    h2b[1] = 0;
    h2b[2] = 0;
    h2b[3] = 0;
  }
  else if ( h2 == 1 ) 
  {
    h2b[0] = 1;
    h2b[1] = 0;
    h2b[2] = 0;
    h2b[3] = 0;
  }
  else if ( h2 == 2) 
  {
    h2b[0] = 0;
    h2b[1] = 1;
    h2b[2] = 0;
    h2b[3] = 0;
  }
  else if ( h2 == 3 ) 
  {
    h2b[0] = 1;
    h2b[1] = 1;
    h2b[2] = 0;
    h2b[3] = 0;
  }
  else if ( h2 == 4 ) 
  {
    h2b[0] = 0;
    h2b[1] = 0;
    h2b[2] = 1;
    h2b[3] = 0;
  }
  else if ( h2 == 5 ) 
  {
    h2b[0] = 1;
    h2b[1] = 0;
    h2b[2] = 1;
    h2b[3] = 0;
  }
  else if ( h2 == 6 ) 
  {
    h2b[0] = 0;
    h2b[1] = 1;
    h2b[2] = 1;
    h2b[3] = 0;
  }
  else if ( h2 == 7 ) 
  {
    h2b[0] = 1;
    h2b[1] = 1;
    h2b[2] = 1;
    h2b[3] = 0;
  }
  else if ( h2 == 8 ) 
  {
    h2b[0] = 0;
    h2b[1] = 0;
    h2b[2] = 0;
    h2b[3] = 1;
  }
  else if ( h2 == 9 ) 
  {
    h2b[0] = 1;
    h2b[1] = 0;
    h2b[2] = 0;
    h2b[3] = 1;
  }

  //m1 - converting to boolean array
  boolean m1b[3];
  if ( m1 == 0 ) 
  {
    m1b[0] = 0;
    m1b[1] = 0;
    m1b[2] = 0;
  }
  else if ( m1 == 1 ) 
  {
    m1b[0] = 1;
    m1b[1] = 0;
    m1b[2] = 0;
  }
  else if ( m1 == 2) 
  {
    m1b[0] = 0;
    m1b[1] = 1;
    m1b[2] = 0;
  }
  else if ( m1 == 3 ) 
  {
    m1b[0] = 1;
    m1b[1] = 1;
    m1b[2] = 0;
  }
  else if ( m1 == 4 ) 
  {
    m1b[0] = 0;
    m1b[1] = 0;
    m1b[2] = 1;
  }
  else if ( m1 == 5 ) 
  {
    m1b[0] = 1;
    m1b[1] = 0;
    m1b[2] = 1;
  }

  //m2 - converting to boolean array
  boolean m2b[4];
  if ( m2 == 0 ) 
  {
    m2b[0] = 0;
    m2b[1] = 0;
    m2b[2] = 0;
    m2b[3] = 0;
  }
  else if ( m2 == 1 ) 
  {
    m2b[0] = 1;
    m2b[1] = 0;
    m2b[2] = 0;
    m2b[3] = 0;
  }
  else if ( m2 == 2) 
  {
    m2b[0] = 0;
    m2b[1] = 1;
    m2b[2] = 0;
    m2b[3] = 0;
  }
  else if ( m2 == 3 ) 
  {
    m2b[0] = 1;
    m2b[1] = 1;
    m2b[2] = 0;
    m2b[3] = 0;
  }
  else if ( m2 == 4 ) 
  {
    m2b[0] = 0;
    m2b[1] = 0;
    m2b[2] = 1;
    m2b[3] = 0;
  }
  else if ( m2 == 5 ) 
  {
    m2b[0] = 1;
    m2b[1] = 0;
    m2b[2] = 1;
    m2b[3] = 0;
  }
  else if ( m2 == 6 ) 
  {
    m2b[0] = 0;
    m2b[1] = 1;
    m2b[2] = 1;
    m2b[3] = 0;
  }
  else if ( m2 == 7 ) 
  {
    m2b[0] = 1;
    m2b[1] = 1;
    m2b[2] = 1;
    m2b[3] = 0;
  }
  else if ( m2 == 8 ) 
  {
    m2b[0] = 0;
    m2b[1] = 0;
    m2b[2] = 0;
    m2b[3] = 1;
  }
  else if ( m2 == 9 ) 
  {
    m2b[0] = 1;
    m2b[1] = 0;
    m2b[2] = 0;
    m2b[3] = 1;
  }

  //s1 - converting to boolean array
  boolean s1b[3];
  if ( s1 == 0 ) 
  {
    s1b[0] = 0;
    s1b[1] = 0;
    s1b[2] = 0;
  }
  else if ( s1 == 1 ) 
  {
    s1b[0] = 1;
    s1b[1] = 0;
    s1b[2] = 0;
  }
  else if ( s1 == 2 ) 
  {
    s1b[0] = 0;
    s1b[1] = 1;
    s1b[2] = 0;
  }
  else if ( s1 == 3 ) 
  {
    s1b[0] = 1;
    s1b[1] = 1;
    s1b[2] = 0;
  }
  else if ( s1 == 4 ) 
  {
    s1b[0] = 0;
    s1b[1] = 0;
    s1b[2] = 1;
  }
  else if ( s1 == 5 ) 
  {
    s1b[0] = 1;
    s1b[1] = 0;
    s1b[2] = 1;
  }


  //s2 - converting to boolean array
  boolean s2b[4];
    if ( s2 == 0 ) 
  {
    s2b[0] = 0;
    s2b[1] = 0;
    s2b[2] = 0;
    s2b[3] = 0;
  }
  else if ( s2 == 1 ) 
  {
    s2b[0] = 1;
    s2b[1] = 0;
    s2b[2] = 0;
    s2b[3] = 0;
  }
  else if ( s2 == 2) 
  {
    s2b[0] = 0;
    s2b[1] = 1;
    s2b[2] = 0;
    s2b[3] = 0;
  }
  else if ( s2 == 3 ) 
  {
    s2b[0] = 1;
    s2b[1] = 1;
    s2b[2] = 0;
    s2b[3] = 0;
  }
  else if ( s2 == 4 ) 
  {
    s2b[0] = 0;
    s2b[1] = 0;
    s2b[2] = 1;
    s2b[3] = 0;
  }
  else if ( s2 == 5 ) 
  {
    s2b[0] = 1;
    s2b[1] = 0;
    s2b[2] = 1;
    s2b[3] = 0;
  }
  else if ( s2 == 6 ) 
  {
    s2b[0] = 0;
    s2b[1] = 1;
    s2b[2] = 1;
    s2b[3] = 0;
  }
  else if ( s2 == 7 ) 
  {
    s2b[0] = 1;
    s2b[1] = 1;
    s2b[2] = 1;
    s2b[3] = 0;
  }
  else if ( s2 == 8 ) 
  {
    s2b[0] = 0;
    s2b[1] = 0;
    s2b[2] = 0;
    s2b[3] = 1;
  }
  else if ( s2 == 9 ) 
  {
    s2b[0] = 1;
    s2b[1] = 0;
    s2b[2] = 0;
    s2b[3] = 1;
  }

  Serial.print('H');
  Serial.print(h1);
  Serial.print(h2);
  Serial.print('M');
  Serial.print(m1);
  Serial.print(m2);
  Serial.print('S');
  Serial.print(s1);
  Serial.print(s2);
  Serial.println();

  // setting up pin booleans
  boolean combiBi[24] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
  combiBi[23] = 0;
  combiBi[22] = 0;
  combiBi[21] = 0;
  combiBi[20] = 0;
  combiBi[19] = h1b[1];
  combiBi[18] = h1b[0];
  combiBi[17] = h2b[3];
  combiBi[16] = h2b[2];
  combiBi[15] = h2b[1];
  combiBi[14] = h2b[0];
  combiBi[13] = m1b[2];
  combiBi[12] = m1b[1];
  combiBi[11] = m1b[0];
  combiBi[10] = m2b[3];
  combiBi[9] = m2b[2];
  combiBi[8] = m2b[1];
  combiBi[7] = m2b[0];
  combiBi[6] = s1b[2];
  combiBi[5] = s1b[1];
  combiBi[4] = s1b[0];
  combiBi[3] = s2b[3];
  combiBi[2] = s2b[2];
  combiBi[1] = s2b[1];
  combiBi[0] = s2b[0];

  // printing out binary for pins
  for(int o = 23; o > 0; o--){
    
    if ( o == 19 )
    {
      Serial.print('H');
    }
    else if (o == 13) 
    {
      Serial.print('M');
    }
        else if (o == 6) 
    {
      Serial.print('S');
    }
    
    Serial.print(combiBi[o]);
  }
  Serial.println();

}
```

`

[Serial Monitor Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jQoy.png)

I tried to get a decimal and binary equivilant output printed in the serial monitor, however the binary is only updated on every other cycle while the decimal performs as expect.

Comment: I don't even know where to begin. probably the best advice is to enter ctrl + A, delete and start over after doing some research on digital numbers and bit manipulation.

Comment: @Piglet
okej fair enough, but could you atleast tell me why the arrary assignment only works every other loop?

Comment: it should be quite obvious that the only reason why a binary number should update only every second turn is that you're missing the last bit. your loop terminates prematurely as you never reach 0...   please follow my advice and start over after learning more about digital numbers. at least count the digits your printing and compare it vs the number you expect next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int o = 23; o > 0; o--)
```

In this loop `o` will never reach 0. Hence you'll never print your last bit which changes every second.

Change your run condition to `o >= 0`.

As already mentioned in my comments you should really learn more about digital numbers and their representation in memory. You don't have to explicitly implement every single bit combination by hand using arrays.
This is a computer, let it compute.